Formula for set-valued mapping whose graph is a linear subspace

Question: Let $A: \mathbb{R}^n \rightrightarrows \mathbb{R}^m$ be a set-valued mapping such that $\mathrm{gph} A$ is a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m$. Prove that
$$\forall x \in \mathrm{dom}A, \quad A(x) = A_0(x) + A(0) $$
for some single-valued linear operator $A_0: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$. Give an explicit construction for $A_0$ if possible.

I see that we can easily conclude that $\mathrm{dom} A$ and $A(0)$ are linear subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$, respectively. However, I cannot figure out the way to construct the single-valued mapping $A_0$. I thought of defining $A_0$ to be the orthogonal projector of an $y \in A(x)$ onto the linear subspace $A(0)$, but I cannot see how we can take the appropriate $y$. Could you give me a hint here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
